# Custom loss function in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I have a seq2seq model where my inputs are short sentences like

```
x = "The XYZ pub near Cafe ABC has a 5 star rating.  Prices start at £30."
```

and my outputs are semantic info extracted from the input sentence like:

```
y_true = name[XYZ], type[pub], price[moderate], rating[5], close_to[Cafe ABC]
```

the problem is that although in many cases my t_true contains the complete semantic info but in certain cases it has missing info like

```
y_true = name[XYZ], type[pub]
```

What I want to do is, even if the model predicts:

```
y_predicted = name[XYZ], type[pub], price[moderate], rating[5], close_to[Cafe ABC]
```

and if

```
y_true = name[XYZ], type[pub]
```

the loss function should also look back in the input and check if the the predicted semantic info which are not in the target are located in the input, and if they are in the input, the cost should be zero.

The comparison of the y_predicted and input x will be a regex matching. Is it possible to integrate a complex process like this in an loss function and particularly in tensorflow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolutely, and in fact it's quite simple to do. For a single sample you are computing a vector of 5 loss values, something like `losses = [1.2, 0.3, 1.5, 3.3, 0.6]`. Note that this result is before you perform any `tf.reduce_mean` functions on your loss.

Now build yourself a function in tensorflow that produces a result of 1 or 0 for each of these loss values to indicate whether you want to zero it out (0) or keep it (1). You now have `mask = [1 1 0 0 0]` based on the example where you want to keep name and type and zero out the loss for the other three.

Now you multiply `final_loss = losses * mask` to get your final loss values, apply `tf.reduce_mean` now and pass that into your optimizer. The key point to note is that this does what you want in gradient descent because `1x = dx` and `0x = 0` when you take the derivatives, so you end up zeroing out the gradient in the cases that shouldn't apply. This is how an RNN with variable sequence lengths works when it's passed in dummy padded values, it zeros out the gradient using a mask.

Comment: Thanks this is a very neat solution.